# javascript loop through array and add html tags depending on symbols

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
const desc = document.getElementById('desc')
const overview = document.getElementById('overview')

btn.addEventListener('click', submitDesc)


function submitDesc() {
  desc.value.split(' ').forEach(element => {
    if (element.startsWith('*') && element.endsWith('*')) {
      let tag = `<h1>${element.substring(1, element.length - 1)}</h1>`

      overview.innerHTML += tag
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<textarea id="desc" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button id='btn'>Add Description</button>

<div id='overview'>

</div>
```

**Sample Description**

```
*Hello World*, this is a h1 tag.
```

Here I have a function splits the description but the problem is that when there are multiple words that are contained in symbols like ** (** = h1 tag) it gets split too and because of that the tags cannot be set, how can I detect and not split words that are in contained in symbols and properly loop through all the words and display them in the overview div.

Comment: Better approach would be to use *regex*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented this with regex. here you go. try execute this code snippet by clicking `run code snippet`.

IMO, it shouldn't be implemented by scratch. use markdown lib if possible. there will be so many extreme cases that can't be easily guessed, if such function is disclosed to general audiences.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
const desc = document.getElementById('desc')
const overview = document.getElementById('overview')

btn.addEventListener('click', submitDesc)


function submitDesc() {
  const text = desc.value;
  const re = /\*([^*]+)+\*/g;
  const replacer = (_, internal) => {
    return `<h1>${internal}</h1>`
  }
  overview.innerHTML = desc.value.replace(re, replacer)
}
```

```html
<textarea id="desc" cols="30" rows="10">*Hello World*, this is a h1 tag.</textarea>
<button id='btn'>Add Description</button>

<div id='overview'>
here is result
</div>
```